# Journey data in Decision split

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud

I have a journey.
My entry source is a DE that updates daily.
I set decision split.
In the first path only those who have purchased  Product = A.
In the second path product = B
(I used journey data)

The customerID "1245" enters the first path because it satisfies the criterion.
The next day the same customerID bought the product = B, so my DE updates.

Will the customer enter the second path if I used journey data in decision split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't because journey data is static. It is the data for the contact at the time of entry and does not change as per your Data Extension. You can read detailed explanation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5). You should use contact data.